# Pointers and functions in c

Tags: c

Please consider the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int fun(); /* function prototype */

int main()
{
    int (*p)() = fun;
    (*p)();  
    return 0;
}
int fun()
{
    printf("IndiaBix.com\n");
    return 0;
}
```

What is `int(*p)()` here?Is it a function,variable or what?

Comment: p is a function pointer points to a funtion that returns a value of type int.

Comment: When in doubt, just use cdecl.org: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%28%2Ap%29%28%29.

Comment: Some info on function pointers: http://www.newty.de/fpt/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flow [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) :

```
                 +------+
                 |      |
                 |  +-+ |
                 |  ^ | |            
             int ( *p ) ()
               ^ |    | |
               | +----+ |
               +--------+

               Identifier p
                 is a pointer to..
                 is a pointer to a function  
                 is a pointer to a function returning int
```

Answer (score 1):

p is a pointer. the `(*p)()` means he is a pointer to a function . `int (*p)()` also means the function it points to return integer.

Answer (score 0):

`int(*p)()` - `p` is a pointer to function which receives nothing and returns an `int`.

p is therefore a variable ofc.

Comment: Actually in C it can receive any number of parameters, since it is not declared as `(void)`.